# Sqlite database login system

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, system

I'm trying to create a login system for an android app and I would like to know if creating a Sqlite database solution would work across different devices. For example if I register in a device, could I access the app from another device with that same account without having to register again? If that does not work, what would be the solution? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You do realize your DB should be on the server, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For allowing same user to loggin in different devices with same credentials in the app you need to use central database .**

Below is the link which will help you a lot.

> http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

**Note : Sqlite database is the local database , we can not use it for our central purpose or out of the specific device.**

Answer (score 2):

Ideal solution would be to connect the app to the server for authentication and authorization. The server can be build using any type of database whether it is sqlite or mysql etc. So it does not make any difference.

You can create a web service for the purpose of authentication using php, java or .net (your choice) and the android application can use any web service client framework such as service stack etc. for connecting to the web service.

What kind of authentication and other features you want will depend solely on your application design.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is using a web server.  I am doing the same and am using a .net web services for users authentication